# How to find all files by a certain modified date in cpanel?

Tags: cpanel, search, file-manager

Let's say you have been hacked and you found one file and now have an estimated time of what files to look for to clean the site. This is quite a mission on a large site.

Is there any way or tools that can find files based on modified date/time?

Comment: is this specific to godaddy, or are you looking for a more general answer?

Comment: @Mousey This is a more general question, but answers specific to godaddy are welcome. You never know if someone stumbles across this question searching for an answer to godaddy's cpanel.

Comment: (Where did "GoDaddy" come from - it's not mentioned at all in the question? cPanel is a widely used hosting control panel - it's not specific to GoDaddy.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use File Manager in cPanel to sort files by "Last Modified" however, this can only be done folder by folder.

This will allow you to look for any abnormal dates.